# Issue with installing ansible-galaxy azure.azcollection

Tags: ansible-galaxy

```
[root@jenkins-dev playbooks]# ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection 
ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: cannot import name 'CollectionRequirement' from 'ansible.galaxy.collection' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/galaxy/collection/__init__.py)
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible-galaxy", line 92, in <module>
    mycli = getattr(__import__("ansible.cli.%s" % sub, fromlist=[myclass]), myclass)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/galaxy.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ansible.galaxy.collection import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'CollectionRequirement' from 'ansible.galaxy.collection' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/galaxy/collection/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 5):

This exception indicates you have overlapping conflicting installations of `ansible-core` (or `ansible-base`) and ansible<2.10.

You will need to clean up your installs to resolve the issue. Potentially via:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall -y ansible-base ansible-core
```

And then install again:

```
$ sudo pip install ansible-base ansible-core
```

Comment: Thanks! I had it installed both via pip and dnf, removing it on pip that did the trick.